# Developing recursive formulas in the theory of probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recursion

I am solving problems from the book *Introduction to probability by Dimitri P. Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsiklis* and there came a series of problems in which you have to develop **recursive formulas for probability.**

Here is the problem I have the trouble with:

> Two players take turns removing a ball from a jar that initially
> contains m white and k black balls. The first player to remove a white
> ball wins. Develop a recursive formula that allows the convenient
> computation of the probability that the starting player wins.

Solution:

> $$p(m,k)=\frac{m}{m+k}+\frac{k}{m+k}\left(1-p(m,k-1\right))$$

**My question is**:

1. What is the logic behind the $$(1-p(m,k-1))$$
2. Are there any useful resources where I can learn about recursion in probability?

Comment: You say that there are $n$ black balls, but the recursion uses $k$ instead. Is this unintentional, or does $k$ mean something else?

Comment: Edited it out, thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started with $m$ white balls and $k$ black balls.

- Probability that  you get a white ball at the first draw is $\frac{m}{m+k}$
- Suppose the first draw is not white, that happens with probability $\frac{k}{m+k}$, then we have to multiply with the probability that the second player lose. Now the second player starts the new game with $m$ white balls and $k-1$ black balls, the probability that he lose is $1-p(m,k-1)$

Hence the formula.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought but wasn't sure as this is the first time I see recursion used in probability.